# calling submit without a button when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to call "onSubmit" when a checkbox is checked using the html input tag?
There is no button.

Regards,
rsmitha.

Comment: I downvoted for no indication of research or any attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,. Basically you have to call the submit method of the form with Javascript, in a click event for the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event on the input tag with some javascript to submit the form.

For example:

```
<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" onchange="document['FormName'].submit();">
```